# Where are Stellaris save games located?

Tags: stellaris

I'm looking to upload a save file in some Stellaris bugs I am reporting, but to do that, I need to be able to find them on my PC.

What folder do Stellaris games get saved to? Is it different with cloud synch enabled? Does Ironman mode make a difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this [wiki](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Save-game_editing), the save game files are located here,

> `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Paradox Interactive\Stellaris\save games\$EMPIRENAME+ID\`

It does not seem to indicate any difference for different game modes, or if cloud synch is enabled, however the save game files are zipped.

> The savegames are zipped. In order to edit them, you'll need to extract them. There are two text files: gamestate and meta. meta includes the information that is shown on the load game screen. gamestate is the actual save game.

Comment: Appears the Ironman difference is purely "cosmetic" -- there's guarenteed to be only the one file, and its named (instead of being user-name-able) "ironman".

Answer (score 4):

OS / Location

**Windows:**

%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Paradox Interactive\Stellaris\save games\$EMPIRENAME+ID\

**Mac:**

$HOME/Documents/Paradox Interactive/Stellaris/save games/$EMPIRENAME+ID

**Linux:**

$HOME/.local/share/Paradox Interactive/Stellaris/save games/$EMPIRENAME+ID

**Linux (newer versions)**:

$STEAMFOLDER/userdata/$STEAMID/281990/remote/save games/$EMPIRENAME+ID