# Can't complete the Unbiden crisis - unconquerable planet

Tags: stellaris

During the Unbidden crisis, the initial portal spawned in a system that had one colonised planet. After dealing with the Unbidden fleets and the portal, this planet stays as occupied by Unbidden, why nominally belonging to another empire.

Yet the population on this planet hasn't been exterminated - in fact it seems that no one can do anything about this planet! There are about dozen fleets from all empires hovering above it, yet there is no option to actually land and attack, with tooltip saying that I can't invade a neutral empire.

I've tried to declare war at the empire nominally owning this planet but even with that, I had no option of landing armies or using colossus on this planet - this time the planet doesn't even react on the right click to give such option.

Is there a way to fix this somehow? I can't load old saves, I'm playing in Ironman mode

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this bug?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, there is no way of fixing this.

As quoted below from the official [Stellaris Wiki (Crisis)](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Crisis), normally once an Unbidden reaches a habitable planet, that planet becomes a barren world:

> If any fleet reaches the orbit of a habitable planet the planet will be stripped of all life and turned into a gray barren world that can be terraformed.

Now because this scenario didn't happen in your current game, and I have personally never experienced this case nor ever heard anyone experiencing this, I am assuming that is unfortunately a bug. My guess is the planet in question should have become a barren world but that for some reason it is in an odd state where you interact with it.

You can read more information about the Unbidden [here](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Crisis#Extradimensional_Invaders).

---

Additionally, since you are playing in Ironman mode, you can't revert back to older saves. Indeed, as quoted from the official [Stellaris Wiki (Ironman)](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Ironman), there is only a single encrypted save file.

> Only a single save will be stored; it is thus impossible to load an earlier save if something goes wrong (unfortunately, this includes save game corruption).
>
> The game saves automatically whenever almost any decision is taken (such as declaring war).
>
> The game saves automatically whenever almost any decision is taken (such as declaring war).

This file is accessible, but even if you do access it it won't be of any use since the game keeps overwriting that save file, so the last state where your game didn't have the bug has probably been overwritten for a long time.

If you still wish to retrieve the save file if you believe you can find a way to edit it, check [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/265286/153536), or read more about the file location [here](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Ironman). But I would just keep on playing if I were you and assume that the planet has been affected by the Unbidden as it should have been.

Comment: Are you 100% sure ironman save are encrypted? I know I've edited my ironman saves in the past, but maybe they patched in encryption for them since.

Comment: @Fambida yes I'm 100%, the developers said that the saves are encrypted. As you say it might have been different in the past. I'm not even sure you could fix that bug through the save file, but if you do figure something out please let me know!

Comment: I just unzipped a freshly made savegame in ironman mode, and it is NOT encrypted. I have most of the major DLC including the latest, Apocalypse. Evidently the devs lied. I'm not sure how you would go about fixing that bug, but the savefile is in pretty plain text, so it should be possible to figure out.

Comment: @Fambida interesting, maybe it was encrypted in the past and they simply forgot to update the section about savefiles